# Pass array to cmdlet in c# using System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a cmdlet in C# and I'd like to be able to pass an array after three mandatory parameters, e.g.

```
Set-PersistedVariables "IDKey1", "IDKey2", "C:\temp\Store", "VarName1", "VarValue1", "VarName2", "VarValue2", "VarNameN", "VarValueN"
```

Or something like that. Any idea how I'd structure my Parameters in the C# Cmdlet and write the call in Powershell?

I did find [Powershell hashtables as argument to custom cmdlet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144477/powershell-hashtables-as-argument-to-custom-cmdlet-in-c-sharp) but was lost on if that applied to my situation or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array parameter that is read from the pipline.

```
[Cmdlet("Set", "PersistedVariables")]
public class SetPersistedVariablesCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true, Position = 0)]
  public string[] InputArray {get;set;}
  protected override void ProcessRecord()
  {
    var yourArray = InputArray;
  }
}
```

Parameters declared in the form:

```
Set-PersistedVariables "IDKey1", "IDKey2", "C:\temp\Store", "VarName1", "VarValue1", "VarName2", "VarValue2", "VarNameN", "VarValueN"
```

Will be coerced silently from `object[]` to `string[]` on invocation.